I am working on a mini weather app using Rapid API for my web dev class but for some reason my web page isn't loading all of my changes
This is JAVASCRIPT code:

//this function will get IP number from ipify API
function getIP() {
    const data = fetch("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json")
        
    .then( function(responseData){

        if (responseData.ok) return responseData.json();
        else return Promise.reject(responseData);

        }) 
    
    .then( function(responseJSON) {
        // everything worked, output info
        console.log("IP number: " + responseJSON.ip);

        // call weather API
        getWeather(responseJSON.ip);

        })

    .catch( function(error){
        console.log("IP error:" + error);
    });

}


//get weather from RapidAPI weather api based on passed IP number
function getWeather(e){

    const url = 'https://weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com/current.json?q=' + e;
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'X-RapidAPI-Key': '9990b72cc3msh8189499bc9e6162p1008e6jsnafd5556ed080',
            'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com'
        }
    };

    console.log("weatherapi accessed");

    let data = fetch(url, options)
        .then( function(response) {
            if (response.ok) return response.json();
            else return Promise.reject(response);
        })

        .then(function(responseJSON) {
            console.log("Weather object: ");
            console.log(responseJSON);
            console.log("Temp in F: " + responseJSON.current.temp_f);
            document.querySelector("#tempF span").innerHTML = responseJSON.current.temp_f;
            document.querySelector("#tempC span").innerHTML = responseJSON.current.temp_c;
            document.querySelector("#weatherIcon").src = responseJSON.current.condition.icon;
            document.querySelector("#weatherText").innerHTML = responseJSON.current.condition.text;
            document.querySelector("#windMPH span").innerHTML = responseJSON.current.wind_mph;
            document.querySelector("#windKPH span").innerHTML = responseJSON.current.wind_kph;
            document.querySelector("#windDirection").innerHTML = responseJSON.current.wind_degree;
            document.querySelector("#humidity span").innerHTML = responseJSON.current.humidity;
            document.querySelector("#cloudCover span").innerHTML = responseJSON.current.cloud;
            document.querySelector("#city").innerHTML = responseJSON.location.name;
            document.querySelector("#state").innerHTML = responseJSON.location.region;        
        })

        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Weather API error: " + error);

        });
}  


// function to sumbit modals
function toggleModal() {
    document.querySelector("#modalCover").classList.toggle("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#modalPopup").classList.toggle("hidden");
}





// wait until DOM loads
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    // show modal
    let formToSubmit = document.querySelector("#formBox");
        formToSubmit.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault(); // don't let form submit

        // examine form code values
        let city = document.querySelector("#city").value;
        getWeather(city);

        let state = document.querySelector("#state").value;
        getWeather(state);
        toggleModal(); // show/hide modal

    });  

    
    
});

Here is my HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <!-- meta tags and title -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simple Weather Demo</title>

    <!-- external and internal CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="all">
    <style>
        /* in-file CSS here */
    </style>

    <!-- external and internal JavaScript -->
    <script src="scripts.js" defer></script>
    <script>
        // in-page JavaScript here
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="modalCover" class="hidden"></div>

    <div id="modalPopup" class="hidden">
        <form id="formBox">
            <p>Input Your City And State</p><br>
            <p><label for="city">City:</label> <input type="text" name="city" id="city" required></p>
            <p><label for="state">State:</label><input type="text" name="state" id="state" required></p>                                                                    </p>
            <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
            <button type="reset" id="cancel">Cancel</button>

        </form>
    </div>

    

    <header><a href="/tp8/index.html">Simple Weather App</a></header>

    <div class="contentBox">
       <div id="temp">
            <h2>Temp</h2>
                <p id="tempF">0<span></span>°F</p>
                <p id="tempC">0<span></span>°C</p> 
       </div>  
       
       <div id="weather">
            <h2>Weather Condition</h2>
                <p id="condition"><span>Light Rain</span></p>
                <img id="weatherIcon" src = "">
       </div>

       <div id="wind">
            <h2>Wind</h2>
                <p id="windMPH">Wind Speed:<span> 0 </span> MPH </p>
                <p id="windKPH"><span>0</span> KPH</p>
                <p id="windDirection"><span class="direction">Direction:</span><span class="degree"> 0 </span>°</p>
       </div>

       <div id="humidity">
            <h2>Humidity</h2>
                <p id="humidity">Humidity:<span> 0 </span>%</p>
       </div>

       <div id="cloudCover">
            <h2>Cloud Cover</h2>
                <p id="cloudCover"><span> 0 </span>%</p>
       </div>
    </div>

    



</body>
</html>


Here is my CSS for reference:
/*---Styling---*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rokkitt:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(186, 158, 158);
}

header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgb(255, 184, 122);
    border-radius: 28px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

a {
    font-family: "Rokkitt", sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    display: flex;
    color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-decoration: none;
    align-items: center;
}

.contentBox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
  
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: bisque;
}

/*contentbox text*/
h2 {
font-size: 50px;
font-family: "Rokkitt", sans-serif;

color: rgb(142, 49, 18);
}

p {
font-size: 25px;
font-family: "Rokkitt", sans-serif;
}

#modalCover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
}

#modalPopup {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30vw;
    height: 60vh;
    left: 35vw;
    top: 20vh;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: rgb(210, 151, 49);
    border: 6px solid rgb(81, 52, 6);
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 200%;

}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    
}

I am still fairly new at javascript so if there is some errors that I am missing that someone with better experience can see in my code, please let me know so I can fix it! thanks!
I have tried rewriting my code according to my instructor but my page refuses to load my popup form that would allow a user to input their city and state and get weather data.

The initial state is that the modal is hidden. You need some action to make the modal visible. Here, I created a button with the text "Show modal" and an event listener on the button that calls the toggleModal function.
There is a lot more I would have done differently, but this is the answer for the question given.


//this function will get IP number from ipify API
function getIP() {
  const data = fetch("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json")

    .then(function(responseData) {

      if (responseData.ok) return responseData.json();
      else return Promise.reject(responseData);

    })

    .then(function(responseJSON) {
      // everything worked, output info
      console.log("IP number: " + responseJSON.ip);

      // call weather API
      getWeather(responseJSON.ip);

    })

    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("IP error:" + error);
    });

}


//get weather from RapidAPI weather api based on passed IP number
function getWeather(e) {

  const url = 'https://weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com/current.json?q=' + e;
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': '9990b72cc3msh8189499bc9e6162p1008e6jsnafd5556ed080',
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
  };

  console.log("weatherapi accessed");

  let data = fetch(url, options)
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.ok) return response.json();
      else return Promise.reject(response);
    })

    .then(function(responseJSON) {
      console.log("Weather object: ");
      console.log(responseJSON);
      console.log("Temp in F: " + responseJSON.current.temp_f);
      document.querySelector("#tempF span").innerHTML = responseJSON.current.temp_f;
      document.querySelector("#tempC span").innerHTML = responseJSON.current.temp_c;
      document.querySelector("#weatherIcon").src = responseJSON.current.condition.icon;
      document.querySelector("#weatherText").innerHTML = responseJSON.current.condition.text;
      document.querySelector("#windMPH span").innerHTML = responseJSON.current.wind_mph;
      document.querySelector("#windKPH span").innerHTML = responseJSON.current.wind_kph;
      document.querySelector("#windDirection").innerHTML = responseJSON.current.wind_degree;
      document.querySelector("#humidity span").innerHTML = responseJSON.current.humidity;
      document.querySelector("#cloudCover span").innerHTML = responseJSON.current.cloud;
      document.querySelector("#city").innerHTML = responseJSON.location.name;
      document.querySelector("#state").innerHTML = responseJSON.location.region;
    })

    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Weather API error: " + error);

    });
}


// function to sumbit modals
function toggleModal() {
  document.querySelector("#modalCover").classList.toggle("hidden");
  document.querySelector("#modalPopup").classList.toggle("hidden");
}



// wait until DOM loads
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  // show modal
  document.querySelector('button[name="showmodal"]').addEventListener('click', e => {
    toggleModal(); // show/hide modal
  });
  
  let formToSubmit = document.querySelector("#formBox");
  formToSubmit.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // don't let form submit

    // examine form code values
    let city = document.querySelector("#city").value;
    getWeather(city);

    let state = document.querySelector("#state").value;
    getWeather(state);
    toggleModal(); // show/hide modal

  });



});
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rokkitt:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(186, 158, 158);
}

header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 184, 122);
  border-radius: 28px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  font-family: "Rokkitt", sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  display: flex;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.contentBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: bisque;
}


/*contentbox text*/

h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Rokkitt", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(142, 49, 18);
}

p {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "Rokkitt", sans-serif;
}

#modalCover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
}

#modalPopup {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 60vh;
  left: 35vw;
  top: 20vh;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: rgb(210, 151, 49);
  border: 6px solid rgb(81, 52, 6);
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 200%;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
<div id="modalCover" class="hidden"></div>

<div id="modalPopup" class="hidden">
  <form id="formBox">
    <p>Input Your City And State</p>
    <p><label for="city">City:</label> <input type="text" name="city" id="city" required></p>
    <p><label for="state">State:</label><input type="text" name="state" id="state" required></p>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
  </form>
</div>
<header><a href="/tp8/index.html">Simple Weather App</a></header>
<button name="showmodal">Show modal</button>
<div class="contentBox">
  <div id="temp">
    <h2>Temp</h2>
    <p id="tempF">0<span></span>°F</p>
    <p id="tempC">0<span></span>°C</p>
  </div>

  <div id="weather">
    <h2>Weather Condition</h2>
    <p id="condition"><span>Light Rain</span></p>
    <img id="weatherIcon" src="">
  </div>

  <div id="wind">
    <h2>Wind</h2>
    <p id="windMPH">Wind Speed:<span> 0 </span> MPH </p>
    <p id="windKPH"><span>0</span> KPH</p>
    <p id="windDirection"><span class="direction">Direction:</span><span class="degree"> 0 </span>°</p>
  </div>

  <div id="humidity">
    <h2>Humidity</h2>
    <p id="humidity">Humidity:<span> 0 </span>%</p>
  </div>

  <div id="cloudCover">
    <h2>Cloud Cover</h2>
    <p id="cloudCover"><span> 0 </span>%</p>
  </div>
</div>




thank you! it works now! Ill have to add some style to the button to fit the styling of my web page. As for the weather data, its only showing the temperature and my icons. Is there anything else I'm doing wrong or need to restructure so all of the weather data is shown?
